# Is turtle.Screen a subclass of turtle.TurtleScreen in python?

Tags: python, screen, python-turtle

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, TurtleScreen
turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
print(isinstance(turtle, Turtle))
print(isinstance(screen, TurtleScreen))
print(issubclass(Screen,TurtleScreen))
print(isinstance(screen, Screen))
```

The last 2 prints got some error, debugging says "Screen" is not a class. But from documentation it says "Screen is a subclass of TurtleScreen". So what's wrong here? Is it related to something called Singolton object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class called `Screen`.  There is a (standalone turtle) function called `Screen` that returns the singleton `TurtleScreen` instance.  So this is correct:

```
screen = Screen()
print(isinstance(screen, TurtleScreen))
```

(The hidden reality is that it is an instance of class `_Screen` which is a subclass of class `TurtleScreen` which is a subclass of `TurtleScreenBase`)

For simplicity, we pretend that we are getting an instance of class `Screen` that we invoke methods on:

```
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(800, 600)
```

But that's a convenient fiction.